# How to convert MM/DD/YYYY to time in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a date in the format:

`MM/DD/YYYY H:MMPM` (not sure how to represent the PM)

How do I covert this into a Ruby datetime representation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to send that string right into `Time.parse` like so:

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > require 'time'
 => true
```

Before Ruby 1.9:

```
2.0.0-p247 :002 > Time.parse("12/1/2014 5:55PM")
 => 2014-12-01 17:55:00 -0500
```

After Ruby 1.9

```
2.0.0-p247 :002 > Time.strptime("12/1/2014 5:55PM","%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p")
 => 2014-12-01 17:55:00 -0500
```

Comment: Ruby is that smart? Amazing! Any idea how to specifcy the timezone offset?

Comment: @kidcapital you can specify a time zone in the string by shortcode (ie `EST`/`CST`) or offset (`-0400`).

Comment: @user2864740, as of Ruby 1.9.3 `Time.parse` no longer parses US style dates (MM/DD/YYYY). Notice in the example that it parsed it non-US style (DD/MM/YYYY). To parse US style be default you need to install https://github.com/jeremyevans/ruby-american_date

Comment: @infused is correct - good catch. I've fixed my example to be more clear

Comment: If you're using Rails you can use `Time.use_zone` if you're dealing with a specific timezone. For example, `Time.use_zone('EST') { Time.zone.parse("08/01/2014 5:00") }`. Just make sure that inside the block you're using `Time.zone`.

Comment: In Ruby 2, I'm getting `NoMethodError: undefined method `strptime' for Time:Class`. I had to `require 'date'` and then use `DateTime.strptime`.

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the `parse` method, or anything based on it, for this.

In the US we use "MM/DD/YYYY" but Ruby, being of a more universal bent, assumes "DD/MM/YYYY", which can cause a lot of failures if the day was > 12. It will also reverse your day and month values.

If today is 'January 2, 2000', `parse` will get the day/month backwards in a US-based date string:

```
DateTime.parse('1/2/2000 12:00AM') # => #<DateTime: 2000-02-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2451576j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

If the date is 'December 31, 2000', `parse` will break:

```
DateTime.parse('12/31/2000 12:00AM') # => 
# ~>  from -:4:in `<main>'
# ~> -:5:in `parse': invalid date (ArgumentError)
# ~>  from -:5:in `<main>'
```

Ruby assumes day is first:

```
DateTime.parse('31/12/2000 12:00AM') # => #<DateTime: 2000-12-31T00:00:00+00:00 ((2451910j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Trying to work around this situation by sniffing the date string will fail. The only way to ensure you can correctly parse date strings is to know the date format used by user or the software that generated the string, or to always use ISO-based strings that are defined to be a certain format.

Instead, forgo the convenience of anything relying on guessing, and tell Ruby what format to use:

```
require 'date'

DateTime.strptime('12/31/2000 12:00AM', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M%p') 
# => #<DateTime: 2000-12-31T00:00:00+00:00 ((2451910j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 1):

In rails, you can just call `.to_time` to a string and it will parse it into a time object

```
2.1.2 :002 > "12/1/2014 5:55PM".to_time
 => 2014-01-12 17:55:00 -0500
```

Comment: I think this parses incorrectly from what the OP wants. They are using MM/DD/YY format

Answer (score 0):

When not being able to rely on a format like ISO 8601, I like to be explicit when parsing dates and times as they can be represented in many different ways. Using [`Time.strptime`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-i-parse),

```
require 'time'
str = "12/1/2014 5:55PM"
d = Time.strptime(str, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p')
# d => 2014-12-01 17:55:00 +0000
```

Notes for the time:

- Use %I ("Hour of the day, 12-hour clock (01..12)"), not %H (which is for 24-hour time)
- Use %M ("Minute of the hour (00..59)"), not %m (which is months)
- Use %p ("Meridian indicator (AM/PM)"), not %P (which is for "am/pm")

The time parsed from above will have a TZ of 0/UTC - solving *that* can of worms is another issue, and it may be easiest just parse the original string with the offset included.

```
tzoff = "-08:00"
d = Time.strptime("#{str} #{tzoff}", '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p %z')
d.localtime(tzoff)  # move back to the right localtime
# d => 2014-12-01 17:55:00 -0800
```